# Xcode 12, React Native app, no simulators displayed anymore

Tags: xcode, react-native, ios-simulator, simulator, xcode12

I am working on a React Native app (which has been expo eject), and I recently upgrade to Xcode 12, but since then my simulators disappears from the list of my different schemes :

[image]

But when I run `xcrun simctl list` I can see simulators and runtimes in the list :

```
== Device Types ==
iPhone 4s (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-4s)
iPhone 5 (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-5)
iPhone 5s (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-5s)
iPhone 6 Plus (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6-Plus)
iPhone 6 (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6)
iPhone 6s (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6s)
iPhone 6s Plus (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6s-Plus)
iPhone SE (1st generation) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-SE)
iPhone 7 (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-7)
iPhone 7 Plus (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-7-Plus)
iPhone 8 (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-8)
iPhone 8 Plus (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-8-Plus)
iPhone X (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-X)
iPhone Xs (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-XS)
iPhone Xs Max (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-XS-Max)
iPhone Xʀ (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-XR)
iPhone 11 (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-11)
iPhone 11 Pro (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-11-Pro)
iPhone 11 Pro Max (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-11-Pro-Max)
iPhone SE (2nd generation) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-SE--2nd-generation-)
iPod touch (7th generation) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPod-touch--7th-generation-)
iPad 2 (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-2)
iPad Retina (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Retina)
iPad Air (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Air)
iPad mini 2 (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-mini-2)
iPad mini 3 (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-mini-3)
iPad mini 4 (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-mini-4)
iPad Air 2 (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Air-2)
iPad Pro (9.7-inch) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Pro--9-7-inch-)
iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (1st generation) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Pro)
iPad (5th generation) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad--5th-generation-)
iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (2nd generation) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Pro--12-9-inch---2nd-generation-)
iPad Pro (10.5-inch) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Pro--10-5-inch-)
iPad (6th generation) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad--6th-generation-)
iPad (7th generation) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad--7th-generation-)
iPad Pro (11-inch) (1st generation) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Pro--11-inch-)
iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (3rd generation) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Pro--12-9-inch---3rd-generation-)
iPad Pro (11-inch) (2nd generation) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Pro--11-inch---2nd-generation-)
iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (4th generation) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Pro--12-9-inch---4th-generation-)
iPad mini (5th generation) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-mini--5th-generation-)
iPad Air (3rd generation) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Air--3rd-generation-)
iPad (8th generation) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad--8th-generation-)
iPad Air (4th generation) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Air--4th-generation-)
Apple TV (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-TV-1080p)
Apple TV 4K (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-TV-4K-4K)
Apple TV 4K (at 1080p) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-TV-4K-1080p)
Apple Watch - 38mm (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-Watch-38mm)
Apple Watch - 42mm (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-Watch-42mm)
Apple Watch Series 2 - 38mm (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-Watch-Series-2-38mm)
Apple Watch Series 2 - 42mm (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-Watch-Series-2-42mm)
Apple Watch Series 3 - 38mm (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-Watch-Series-3-38mm)
Apple Watch Series 3 - 42mm (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-Watch-Series-3-42mm)
Apple Watch Series 4 - 40mm (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-Watch-Series-4-40mm)
Apple Watch Series 4 - 44mm (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-Watch-Series-4-44mm)
Apple Watch Series 5 - 40mm (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-Watch-Series-5-40mm)
Apple Watch Series 5 - 44mm (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-Watch-Series-5-44mm)
Apple Watch SE - 40mm (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-Watch-SE-40mm)
Apple Watch SE - 44mm (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-Watch-SE-44mm)
Apple Watch Series 6 - 40mm (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-Watch-Series-6-40mm)
Apple Watch Series 6 - 44mm (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-Watch-Series-6-44mm)
== Runtimes ==
iOS 14.0 (14.0 - 18A372) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-14-0
tvOS 14.0 (14.0 - 18J383) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.tvOS-14-0
watchOS 7.0 (7.0 - 18R382) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.watchOS-7-0
```

If I create a new project in Xcode, I can see simulators.

I tried to compare build, general and signing settings as scheme settings with another project that see simulators, but could not find any relevant differences.

I can build on device (so project is not too badly setup I guess).

I also tried with latest beta version for Xcode (12.6) with same result.
I did a couple of clean uninstall, reinstalling XCode 12 as well.

I tried to install simulators for iOS 12.0, and 12.4, set the target of the app to 12.0, 12.4, 14.0. All simulators are installed and usable for other projects but not displayed for this project.

It seems to be a setting issue but I can't figure out what is missing/badly set up.

Comment: while I am not sure what the root cause is, I was in a simillar situation and decided to install 11.7 side by side to resolve a different problem with my project. Once I did I reopened Xcode 12 and my simulators list was restored.

Comment: @ElliotRodriguez : I tried, and installed Xcode 11.7 side by side, I couldn't see any simulators in both Xcode 11.7 or beta 12.6, even after I have download iOS 12.0 simulators unfortunately.

When I run `xcrun simctl list` I have this :

`== Runtimes ==
iOS 12.0 (12.0 - 16A366) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-12-0 (unavailable, failed to open liblaunch_sim.dylib)
iOS 14.0 (14.0 - 18A5357e) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-14-0
...`

I still see them on other projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the same problem with an existing project that was working fine with Xcode 11.7. After upgrading to Xcode 12, I wasn't able to select a simulator. When I created a new project, I was able to run that in a simulator so I carefully compared the build settings between the two projects.

I noticed that the Architectures value in the new (working) project was set to $(ARCHS_STANDARD) while the same value in my existing project was set to arm64. Changing the the value to $(ARCHS_STANDARD) fixed the problem.

With your project selected in Xcode, select your build target and then the Build Settings tab. Make sure that All rather than Basic is selected and select Architectures/Architectures. Click on its value and set it to $(ARCHS_STANDARD). You may find that you can select a value called "Standard architectures" that will also set it to the required value.

You should now be able to select from the usual list of simulators in the schema selector at the top of the window.

Comment: Nice ! Yeah doing that fix the issue, I see simulators now and can partially build.
Works fine to build on device, though the build is failing for simulators, but it's because of the project I guess. I have this error : `ld: library not found for -lDoubleConversion` 
The only solution we found before to solve it was to set architecture set to `arm64, arm64e` :s

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was that I have set the `iOS Deployment Target to 13.5` the max `iOS version was 13.4` - I think I accidentally did this by code not from the xcode GUI

open `YourProj.xcworkspace` => and under Project tab select your project name then change the `iOS Deployment Target` to match the ones which your simulators have installed

[image: as in the pic that's all you need to do]

Answer (score 0):

In my case it appears there were architecture settings in the Xcode project that are no longer visible in the Xcode 12 UI.

```
> grep -r VALID_ARCHS ios
ios/MyProject.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj:  VALID_ARCHS = "arm64 arm64e";
ios/MyProject.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj:  VALID_ARCHS = "arm64 arm64e";
```

Removing those with vim then re-opening the project in Xcode had the simulators start showing up again.